Typo3 bash installation failing
Normal installation of TYPO3 v13 is not working

composer create-project typo3/cms-base-distribution example-project-directory "^13" works

./vendor/bin/typo3 setup returns -->



Enter the database - "username" [default: db] ? julian
Enter the database "password" ? password
Enter the database "port" [default: 3306] ? 3306
Enter the database "host" [default: db] ? db
- ☓ [Error]: An exception occurred in the driver: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for db failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known


https://example-project-site.local/typo3/install.php --> doesn't load.

All according to the latest installation docs: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/tutorial-getting-started/main/en-us/Installation/Install.html#run-the-setup-process
@Stefan Bürk
I had to navigate to the example-project-directory folder where the vendor folder is exposed than it worked. But now I have another issue.

☓ [Error]: An exception occurred in the driver: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for db failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known


Just done, works without issues. Can you please provide the output of the composer create-project execution ? Maybe something went wrong here. Note that at aleast a composer 2.2 version is required and PHP 8.2 as minimum. maybe you invoked it with the wrong php/composer versions ? cms-install is optional but included within the base distribution.

@Stefan Bürk composer version 2.7 and php version 8.3 :))

the password in ddev is usually "db" too. YOu didn't mention ddev but you used "db" as host and username like it's done in ddev. if you never use ddev you've to check or configure the connection parameters.

Should I have used ddev? Where do I find the connection parameters to configure? :))

as already mentioned, "db" is the default for the database host - the default takes/suggtest the "ddev defaults". When you don't use ddev you need to provide the host for your database - either the name if it can be resolved or the IP, for example 127.0.0.1 for local mysql/mariadb instances etc.

So: Enter the database "host" [default: db] ? 127.0.0.1 ?
